# How to update in hundreds m scripts a variable definition?

Tags: matlab, rename, automated-refactoring

We have in University hundreds of m scripts and we want to change/update some definitions of the variables. We want to change all the `ufix(*), sfix(*)` to `fixdt(*,*)`. So I imagine that I could make an m-script that read the m-files and changes all the definitions. I think the difficult part of the script is to find for example a `ufix(8)-unsigned 8bit` and to change into `fixdt(0,8)`. 
Do you know a function in Matlab which makes this automatic?

Comment: So ou want to find and replace all instanced of `ufix(` with `fixdt(0,`? Maybe Matlab is not the best tool for this. Maybe try an alternative editor, Atom.io for example lets you load a folder as a project and I'm farily sure you'll be able to do a find a replace across all files in that folder as well as it's subfolders...

Comment: Yeah Matlab is definitely not the best tool for this, you can find best way to do it, either with Windows, Mac & Linux

Comment: @Dan Are u sure that with matlab is impossible ?

Comment: @HamtaroWarrior i can work only in Windows, so could you give me an alternative suggestion!

Comment: @poprock I'm not sure, but I'd be extremely surprised if it did not work. Why don't you just download it and try it out for yourself?

Comment: There are so much ways I don't know where to begin. Just take a look to a [google query](https://www.google.fr/webhp?hl=fr#hl=fr&q=replace+in+multiple+files+windows).

Comment: You simply need a text editor which can apply search and replace operations to multiple files. Choose notepad++, atom.io or whatever you want to use.

Comment: @Daniel i have notepad++ but could you imagine when i have hundreds of scripts with `ufix(8), ufix(16), ufix(32) etc.` i think that is very unpractice

Comment: @Daniel I cannot understand why Matlab is a bad idea and it´s better to use a manual method with Notepad ++. Could you explain me ?

Comment: @poprock: "manual" means selecting the folder, filling out "search" and "replace with" and hit "replace all" to apply the changes to all files.
Unlike IDEs like Eclipse, Matlab has no real refactoring support. Using a text editor is the simplest way to do it, which means doing it in Matlab would require you to write code which does the same text replace steps.

Comment: I'd try with `regexp`

Comment: I use `notepad++` to do the same thing fairly often, you can search/replace literal expressions or even regexp ... across a whole project folder. Even if you have to repeat the process 4 times (for `8/16/32/64` bit cases, it is much easier and quicker than programming all that in Matlab. In any case ... _don't forget to backup before you start global replacement_ !!