# How can i read a text file and save the numbers for further process with Matlab and Java API?

Tags: java, string, matlab

i have a sample of a text file like this :

```
const_param(                                  ...
'func_1'                                      ,... Name
''                                            ,... Description
10                                            ,... Value
ufix(16)                                      ,... DataType
2^0                                           ,... Scale
''                                            ,... Owner
'\user\Desktop\matlab'                        ,... Path
0                                              ... Offset
);
```

and i want to make a parser, to read this file and to have all the numbers in variables with the same name, so i can make a script to work with this values.
An other issue is to update the ufix() function from Matlab.

Which Method from Java is good to recognize every value an to save into a variable with the same name of the file´s description?

I have started to write a test script to do this but i am stuck because this way is very static and i cannot use the values as i want.

below is my script

```
try
fid = fopen(m_file_name, 'r');
tline = fgetl(fid);
while ischar(tline)
    % Use Java string
    sCurrLine = java.lang.String(tline);

    if sCurrLine.matches('^.*ufix\(\d+\).*$')
        sCurrLine = sCurrLine.replaceAll('[u]fix', 'fixdt');
        disp(sCurrLine);

    else sCurrLine.matches('^.*sfix\(\d+\).*$')
          sCurrLine = sCurrLine.replaceAll('[s]fix', 'fixdt');
          disp(sCurrLine);

    end   


    % next line
    tline = fgetl(fid);
end
fclose(fid);
```

Expected Output:

```
const_param(                                  ...
'func_1'                                      ,... Name
''                                            ,... Description
10                                            ,... Value
fixdt(0,16,2^0,0);                            ,... DataType
// 2^0                                        ,... Scale
//''                                          ,... Owner
//'\user\Desktop\matlab'                      ,... Path
//0                                            ... Offset
);
```

Comment: Are you using Matlab or Java?  This code looks like Matlab to me.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I use Matlab with Java API to have more Methods

Comment: You really should also post your expected output.

Comment: That's a much better explanation than your previous question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31510356/how-to-update-in-hundreds-m-scripts-a-variable-definition. But you should precise how is the `fixdt(0,16,2^0,0);` statement populated (which `0` is taken from the `offset` line (if it is) etc ...

Comment: @Hoki This is definitely the final work, i have suggested the solution with Notepad++ and replace but rejected,  they want definitely a script!